# When do I use a self message and a recursive message in UML?

Tags: uml

I came across the following post however had a hard time understanding it - [self message(non recursive) vs self recursive message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626473/self-messagenon-recursive-vs-self-recursive-message).

I also came across the example at http://www.zicomi.com/messageRecursion.jsp hoping a real world scenario would help but that confused me further. Why would you need a recursive message when the order has been passed to the kitchen and chef. I would thought all you would have needed is a self message i.e. the chef completing the order and then passing it to the waiter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chef example is arguably "wrong" in what it shows and describes.

Simply put, a message to *self* just means that the method that is to be invoked next happens to be in the same class of objects. E.g. a call to SavingsAccount.withdraw(anAmount) may call SavingsAccount.getBalance() to determine if there are enough funds to continue with the withdrawal.

A recursive call is a special case of a call to *self* in that it is to the same method (with a different state, so that it can eventually return out of the recursive calls).  Some problems lend themselves to this solution.  An example is factorial (see [Factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29#Factorial)).  To do a factorial without recursion would be impossible (at least for all cases but the simplest, due to the volume of inline code needed). If you look in the factorial code example, you'll see that the call is changed by one each time (*factorial(n-1)*) and stops when *n* reaches zero. Trying to do this inline for a value like 1,000,000 would not be feasible without recursion.

Comment: Can you give me a real world example in place of the chef?